# Even if I already have a master's in clinical psychology, can I apply for another master's in another field of psychology in a different country?

Tags: phd, masters, psychology, abroad

I have received my education in a back to back format, school then bachelor's and immediately after that, master's in clinical psychology. Currently I'm working as a school counselor. It sounds lame to say this but my mother sort of has this obsession with the 'Dr.' that comes before your name after completing Ph.D. and for a while I was on board with  that but then the pandemic happened and it gave me time to think and realize that I was not ready for a Ph.D. at all. I haven't the slightest idea what I want to research on - I thought since I was currently working with kids maybe something related to them but whenever I think about it I feel little to no interest. I've always wanted to go 'study abroad'. The education system in my country has always disappointed me and I've never felt fulfilled by it. But directly going for a Ph.D. in a foreign country seems very daunting and I know that I'm not at all prepared for it. So I figured maybe I could do a master's in another field of psychology, say maybe forensic or criminal or any other area. But I'm not sure if its possible. I am not even sure which country I should focus on although the stats show that it's the U.S. that I should apply to but I want to keep my options open. So please help.

Comment: In some countries yes, in others no. You need to explore the actual regulations. In US, you could probably do so even if your first was there. But that would be up to the individual university as there are no general regulations.

Comment: Sounds like several issues you personally need to work through and, ideally, reconcile. Your title asks about a second masters degree, your text about a PhD. You feel compelled by your mother to get a PhD. You think an educational system could be fulfilling, but isn’t. Seems an appropriate time for you to assess your personal situation, your priorities, your talents and assets, your experiences. For the latter, you’ve been working with children. Maybe start there?

Comment: @Aruralreader Right you can see  how confused I am just from how all over the place my question was. And yes, I'm working with children and for the most part, I enjoy it but it's not mentally stimulating and it does not inspire any sort of, I guess you could say, deep thinking out of me. It just seems like a job. but thank you for your comment. Originally I had felt a little called out and defensive but honestly, you're right. I got to figure my stuff out.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you. Would you by any chance have an idea, even if its just one university, where this is very likely to be accepted. Just so that I could find a starting point for researching.

Comment: No idea, really, but in the US, I'd guess it isn't too hard to find one. Clinical and theoretical are quite different. Specialties such as criminal are also worth exploring. And acceptance depends on the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: good for you for stepping back and thinking about what you really want to do.

To answer your actual question, you can apply anywhere for any program that seems interesting. Whether you're admitted depends on many factors. Some programs might find your background a reason for acceptance, some the opposite. Whether you need financial assistance will probably matter.

I would advise you to cast a broad net. Look at (even apply to) many programs in many places. Then explore the ones that accept you. Please yourself first, hope that your choice pleases your mother.

Good luck. Come back here from time to time to tell us what you are doing.

Comment: Just the fact that there are people out there that are saying that it isn't written anywhere that it technically is NOT possible is a relief in its own. Thank you and I will surely come back and update, if I end up applying and, fingers crossed, get accepted.

Comment: Hmmm, acceptance with no upvotes seems odd to me. But, hey, I can fix that. ;-)